# Error in library("Hmisc"): there is no package called 'Hmisc'

Tags: r, anaconda

I just installed R using anaconda, and I am following this tutorial:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/tutorial-powerful-packages-imputing-missing-values/

I learned that I need to install some package by using:

```
if(!require(Hmisc)) install.packages("Hmisc",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

There are some warning message i am not sure whether it means successful or not:

```
Loading required package: Hmisc
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, : there is no package called 'Hmisc'also installing the dependencies 'survival', 'ggplot2'

Warning message:
In install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): installation of package 'survival' had non-zero exit status
Warning message:
In install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): installation of package 'ggplot2' had non-zero exit status
Warning message:
In install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): installation of package 'Hmisc' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/Rtmpcf6rZ9/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Then I tried to load the library with

```
library(Hmisc)
```

But I got the error,

> Error in library(Hmisc): there is no package called 'Hmisc'

Does anyone know what might has happened? Thanks.

**Edit:**

I am suggested to try a few more ways, but they all have various error:

```
install.packages("Hmisc")
```

> ```
> Error in contrib.url(repos, type): trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
> ```

If I do:

```
install.packages("Hmisc",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

I got:
    also installing the dependencies 'survival', 'ggplot2'

```
Warning message:
In install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): installation of package 'survival' had non-zero exit status
Warning message:
In install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): installation of package 'ggplot2' had non-zero exit status
Warning message:
In install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): installation of package 'Hmisc' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/Rtmpcf6rZ9/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

I am suggested not to use Anaconda R, but because I mostly use rpy2 and jupiter notebook the most. I think using the Anaconda R may be the most straight forward method to get my jupiter notebook and python to work seamlessly with R.

Comment: "installation of package 'Hmisc' had non-zero exit status" means that Hmisc did not install properly. Try just `install.packages("Hmisc")` and take note of the complete error message. Also: users on this forum seem to have nothing but problems using Anaconda R, I suggest you don't use it.

Comment: @neilfws, I edited the question. Please see if it may help...

Comment: I'm surprised that there is not more information in the warning messages. And the error about CRAN simply would not occur using a standard R + RStudio installation, so I remain suspicious of Anaconda.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install "Hmisc" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902174/how-to-install-hmisc-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, solved it by installing "acepack" directly `install.packages('acepack')`

Answer (score 0):

This is mysterious, regardless. I do an update of all packages in Conda. Then, I install Rstudio using anaconda. Then the error does not exist anymore...