# How to install "Hmisc" in R

Tags: r, hmisc

```
install.packages("Hmisc")

Warning in install.packages : unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES' Installing package into
  ‘C:/Users/Tushant/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) 
Warning in install.packages : unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages : package ‘Hmisc’ is not available (for R version 3.4.2)
Warning in install.packages : unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES'
```

Comment: Either a temporary network glitch or you (or your company?) have firewall issues, my guess.

Answer (score 3):

Hmisc package is a depend package. Depend of packages:  survival, lattice, ggplot2, Formula.
you visit https://mran.microsoft.com/package/Hmisc

example:

```
install.packages("survival")
install.packages("lattice")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("Hmisc")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are interest of the answer at your problem, but today I had the same your problem and I resolved this with the download the last version of R software.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 37 - **Hmisc** is not found when executing:
`sudo dnf list R-Hmisc`

The solution in this case was to create `dep-install.r`
and then execute:
`sudo ./dep-install.r`

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

# dep-install.r

# Print a message
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
sayAnnounce <- function(){
    cat("Rscript running...", args[1],sep=" ",fill=TRUE)
}
sayAnnounce()

# Fedora will require:
system("sudo dnf -y install R-jpeg")

### Main Function ###
setup <- function(){
    install.packages("latticeExtra",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
    install.packages("Hmisc",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
    library(Hmisc)
}
setup()
```

We also attempt to load the Hmisc library for additional confirmation.

A platform specific answer like this might not be helpful for a Windows user; but may be useful for those with a `dnf` package manager.